# How to eliminate odd fungi in Solarium

Tags: fungus

Noticed fungi growing in my solarium in a few spots - probably a few spots where moisture is getting in. It is really tough, like rubber. Can cut some of it out with a utility knife, but even that was not an easy process. Couldn't dig all of it out as it has gotten into some little crevices. How can I treat this? Tea tree oil or Oil of Oregano, or ?

Solarium was installed maybe 5 years ago and no growth. Nothing this summer.  Not used much. 
 When I went in today, I saw the growth.  Must be a little leak around that area.  The type of flooring is Bamboo.

The spotty things you see on the floor are spider droppings.. how that critter got in there is a mystery - room is always closed, way up on the 3rd floor where I never see any spiders, room is hardly used, and no openings for little flies or anything to get in for its food...? Anyways, I digress... my real concern is to stop this fungi growth!

Thanks in advance...
[image]

[image]

Comment: I would address the leak first. If it dies off then you know you've solved the leak.

Comment: Have to wait for the summer to re-caulk the exterior seam... thanks for the reply!